# Is the image of a homology basis via a finite degree covering also a homology basis

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces

Suppose that $M$ is the quotient of a  $n$ dimensional torus $T$ by a discrete subgroup of affine isometries of $\mathbb R^n$ without fixed points.

Let $p:T \to M$ be the canonical cover (finite degree covering). If we fix a family of generators of first homology group $H_1(T,\mathbb Z)$ of $T$, is the image of an element of this family of generators by the cover $p$ a non-trivial element in the homology of $M$?

If yes, do the images of this family also form a generating family of the first homology group of $M$?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest you first work out what happens in the case of a covering (of degree two, for example) of the circle by itself.

Comment: The answer to the first question is also no : consider the involution $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,y^{-1})$ of $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$.